# Expand loop over multiple columns in R

Tags: r

I have a table (mydf) as shown below. I would like to use this for loop (my code) in R which works for only one column (for ALT1 column in this instance) to loop over all the columns containing ALT1 through ALTn and store the output in separate variables from final1 through finaln.
The purpose here is to loop over ALT1 through ALTn to match the nucleotide columns (A,C,G,T,N) and get the corresponding values as shown in the result below.Thank you for your help!

> mycode

```
      final1 <- {}
i <- 1
result =merge(coverage.bam, rows.concat.alt, by="start")

for(i in 1:nrow(result)){
  final1[i] = paste(paste(result$chr[i], result$start[i], result$end[i],sep=":"),"-", 
                   result$REF[i],"(",result[,(as.character(result$REF[i]))][i],")",",", result$ALT1[i],
                   "(",result[,(as.character(result$ALT1[i]))][i][!is.na(result[,(as.character(result$ALT1[i]))][i])],")",sep="")

}

final1
```

I have tried to expand this code for ALT through ALTn, but it does not work, could you help me solve this please?

```
final <- list()
setValue<-function(element){
  print(element)
  for(i in 1:nrow(result)){
    final[[i]] = paste(paste(result$chr[i], result$start[i], result$end[i],sep=":"),"-", 
                     result$REF[i],"(",result[,(as.character(result$REF[i]))][i],")",",", result[,element][i],
                     "(",result[,(as.character(result[,element][i])))][i][!is.na(result[,(as.character(result[,element][i])][i])],")",sep="")

  }
}
for(i in colnames(result)){
  if(grepl('ALT', i)){
   setValue(i) 
  }
}
```

> mydf

```
    chr     start       end  A  C  G  T  N  =  - REF ALT ALT1 ALT2 ALT3 ALTn          
1 chr10 102022031 102022031 NA 34 NA NA NA NA NA   C   G    G NA NA NA       
2 chr10 102220574 102220574  2 22  2  3 NA NA NA   C AGT    A    G    T NA       
3 chr10 115322228 115322228 NA 25 NA NA NA NA NA   C   A    A NA NA NA       
4 chr10 122222925 122222925 30 NA NA NA NA NA NA   A   C    C NA NA NA 
5 chr10 121111042 121111042 NA 48 NA NA NA NA NA   C   T    T NA NA NA 
6 chr10 124444484 124444484 NA 60 NA NA NA NA NA   C   T    T NA NA NA
```

> Result

```
"chr10:102022031:102022031-C(34),G()"            "chr10:102220574:102220574-C(22),A(2),G(2),T(3)" "chr10:115322228:115322228-C(25),A()"           
      [4] "chr10:122222925:122222925-A(30),C()"            "chr10:121111042:121111042-C(48),T()"            "chr10:124444484:124444484-C(60),T()"
```

Comment: I just need to extract the values from A,C,G,T,N columns matching with the nucleotides( A,T,G,T) in the ALT1..ALTn columns.

Comment: It is the expected output.

Comment: It is the expected output for the given number of ALT columns but the number of ALT columns  could vary to n.

Comment: I just replaced NAs with empty brackets. So basically I am selecting the value from Reference (REF) column first and then the values for remaining ALT columns.

Comment: I just updated my code in the OP which give me the output for the ALT1 column. Now I need to expand this to columns ALT2..ALTn.

Comment: All the letters are characters , T is the DNA  letter Thymine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 p1 <- do.call(paste,c(mydf[1:3], sep=":"))
 p2 <- apply(mydf[c(4:8, 11:16)], 1, function(x) {
            Un1 <- unique(match( x[7:11], names(x)[1:4], nomatch=0))
            i1 <- match(x[6], names(x))
            v1 <- paste0(names(x[i1]),'(', x[i1], ')')
            v2 <- as.numeric(x[Un1])
            v2[is.na(v2)] <- ''
            v3 <-paste(names(x[Un1]), '(', v2, ')', sep='', collapse=",")
            paste(v1, v3, sep=",") })

 paste(p1, p2, sep="-")
 #[1] "chr10:102022031:102022031-C(34),G()"           
 #[2] "chr10:102220574:102220574-C(22),A(2),G(2),T(3)"
 #[3] "chr10:115322228:115322228-C(25),A()"           
 #[4] "chr10:122222925:122222925-A(30),C()"           
 #[5] "chr10:121111042:121111042-C(48),T()"           
 #[6] "chr10:124444484:124444484-C(60),T()"
```